# Prove a function is not Darboux-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Prove $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 2+x,  & x \in \Bbb Q \\
> 1, & x \notin \Bbb Q
> \end{cases}$  is not integrable on $[0,1]$

**My attempt:**

Let $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1], I_i=[t_{i-1},t_i], m_i=\inf_{I_i}f, M_i=\sup_{I_i}f$

Since there exists at least one irrational number in $I_i$ we have that $m_i=1$

Since there exists at least one rational number in $I_i$ we have that $M_i=2+t_i$ or $M_i \approx  2+t_i$, where $t_i \in \Bbb Q$

$\implies L(f,P)=1-0=1 \ne \displaystyle{\sum _{i=1}^{n}} {M_i(t_i-t_{i-1})=U(f,P)}$, because $M_i \ne m_i$ $\forall i$

**Is this correct? If not, then what can be improved? Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace
$$M_i \approx 2+t_i $$ by

$$M_i\ge 2$$ which is more precise.

then $$M_i-m_i\ge 2-1$$
and
$$U (f,P)-L (f,P)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_i-m_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)\geq 1$$

if we take $\epsilon=\frac {1}{2} $ then for all partition $P $ of $[0,1] $

$$U (f,P)-L (f,P)>\epsilon $$
$f $ is not integrable at $[0,1] $.